# compiling vim with python support on Ubuntu

Tags: python, vim, compilation

I am trying to compile vim from source with python interpreter on Ubuntu. I have installed the dependencies for vim, installed python2.7-devel and python2.7-dbg packages on Ubuntu and do the configure step like this

```
./configure --enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config
```

The config directory does contain the config.c file. The make step fails with the following error.

```
...

objects/py_config.o:(.data+0xcc): undefined reference to `initcStringIO'
objects/py_config.o:(.data+0xd4): undefined reference to `initcPickle'
objects/py_config.o:(.data+0xdc): undefined reference to `initzlib'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [vim] Error 1
```

I have tried stable builds, tweaked around configure etc. But do not find a definitive answer. Also vim builds without the python-interpreter.

Here the complete

output - http://paste.pocoo.org/show/577749/

error - http://paste.pocoo.org/show/577752/

Makefile - http://paste.pocoo.org/show/577751/

Comment: Could you please include more lines of error messages? BTW, this is a linking error, which often happens because of incorrect paths to library. Did you check paths to the libraries?

Comment: Why do you just not try `vim-nox`?

Comment: @eleweek - Included links to output and error.

Comment: Did you `sudo apt-get build-dep vim-common`?

Comment: Yes @AndreyYazu. I did sudo apt-get build-dep vim ( that's the command).

Comment: I'm with @neoascetic.  `vim-nox` (as well as `vim-athena`, `vim-gnome`, and `vim-gtk`) depends on `libpython2.7`; should it not therefore have Python support?

Comment: @zigg - my question is for compilation - my task is itself. not for achieving the end by using some package.

Comment: Still not totally clear why you'd want to build your own in these circumstances, but this might be useful: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=105292  I'd try `make distclean`, then re-`configure` and try again.

Comment: Hey @zigg - Thanks for the pointer. I shall try it. But I am surprised by your question on why. I would like to. That's it.

Comment: That's a fair answer, particularly if the quest is knowledge, but I think the question is also fair.  Asking "why" is useful to get to the heart of a problem that could be answered differently depending on whether you are playing with the builds themselves (in which case I'd recommend looking into how Debian packages themselves are built, too), or perhaps in search of an option not enabled in any package, or maybe just simply unaware that the option you are seeking is already available elsewhere—there may be a better way.  Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question after doing significant research.
Looks in certain Ubuntu installs, the files which vim is looking for [compilation may be missing](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/_xf8hGnPvMk/N1TUwz7csbwJ).

After realizing that I went ahead with custom install of Python source (`./configure --prefix=/home/senthil/localpython; make; make install`) and then proceeded with vim compilation aginst this one.

1. Set your path so that `python` points to the new local install.

   PATH=/home/senthil/localpython/bin:$PATH
2. Then start the compilation with the following flags.

   ./configure  --enable-pythoninterp --with-features=huge --with-python-config-dir=/home/senthil/localpython/lib/python2.7/config

You should see that vim compiles fine with using the local python interpreter. As has been informed by various sources, this increases the size of vim and I also felt that the speed had significant become slower. Just after finishing this exercise (in a really way with patience), I think, I would like to use the system compiled vim itself.

Answer (score 3):

get the configdir with `/usr/bin/python2.7-config --configdir`

ie:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep vim 
hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim
./configure --enable-pythoninterp --with-features=huge --prefix=$HOME/opt/vim --with-python-config-dir=$(/usr/bin/python2.7-config --configdir)
make && make install
```

Answer (score 2):

Before compiling Vim, install `python-dev` and `python2.7-dev` (or whichever dev matches your python version). Those two packages might point to the same files, but it worked for me.

Comment: I think the OP's answer is more sufficient.

Comment: OP's answer is certainly longer, but it didn't work for me. Also, I'd be surprised if it did work. Why does it make sense to give Vim a config file for a Python interp that's not the system Python interp?

Comment: @AlexBeal how do I install python-dev? I am trying to install it on debian (and I have no root privileges)