# Error when compiling Vim with Python 3 Support

Tags: python, vim

Compiling vim from source using --enable-pythoninterp causes no issues but when I try to use --enable-python3interp it correctly finds my anaconda python config directory after running `./configure --prefix=/usr --with-features=huge --enable-python3interp` but then I get this wild error below when I try to launch the vim binary and no clue where to begin troubleshooting this:

thank you but after seeing the below after running ./configure I was under the impression that it found the correct python and config dir also:

```
checking --enable-python3interp argument... yes
checking for python3... (cached) /ebs/anaconda3/bin/python3
checking Python version... (cached) 3.4
checking Python is 3.0 or better... yep
checking Python's abiflags... (cached) m
checking Python's install prefix... (cached) /ebs/anaconda3
checking Python's execution prefix... (cached) /ebs/anaconda3
checking Python's configuration directory... (cached)     /ebs/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m


Vim: Caught deadly signal ABRT
*** glibc detected *** vim: malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted: 0x0000000002c7a950 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x321ec76166]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x321ec79f2f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x71)[0x321ec7a9a1]
vim[0x4c2540]
vim[0x4c3217]
vim[0x4471ba]
vim[0x4693eb]
vim[0x4676e3]
vim[0x45b190]
vim[0x457b1f]
vim[0x42e36a]
vim[0x43c54f]
vim[0x441c40]
vim[0x4405d3]
vim[0x440814]
vim[0x440a81]
vim[0x440e23]
vim[0x4416e4]
vim[0x441844]
vim[0x4422ee]
vim[0x44ada3]
vim[0x4693eb]
vim[0x4676e3]
vim[0x43b9d3]
vim[0x43c47c]
vim[0x441c40]
vim[0x4405d3]
vim[0x440814]
vim[0x440a81]
vim[0x440e23]
vim[0x4416e4]
vim[0x441844]
vim[0x441b59]
vim[0x4405d3]
vim[0x440814]
vim[0x440a81]
vim[0x440e23]
vim[0x4416e4]
vim[0x441844]
vim[0x4422ee]
vim[0x44ada3]
vim[0x4693eb]
vim[0x4676e3]
vim[0x43b9d3]
vim[0x43c47c]
vim[0x441c40]
vim[0x4405d3]
vim[0x440814]
vim[0x440a81]
vim[0x440e23]
vim[0x4416e4]
vim[0x441844]
vim[0x441b59]
vim[0x447de1]
vim[0x4693eb]
vim[0x4676e3]
vim[0x47bc01]
vim[0x47c09a]
vim[0x59848c]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x321f00f710]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x321ec32925]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175)[0x321ec34105]
/ebs/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/../../libpython3.4m.so.1.0(Py_FatalError+0x59)[0x7f5f4d0f3269]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-007e3000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 188515                             /usr/bin/vim
009e2000-00a52000 rw-p 003e2000 ca:01 188515                             /usr/bin/vim
00a52000-00a79000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
028f9000-02d64000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
321e400000-321e420000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450684                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
321e61f000-321e620000 r--p 0001f000 ca:01 450684                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
321e620000-321e621000 rw-p 00020000 ca:01 450684                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
321e621000-321e622000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
321e800000-321e802000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450709                         /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
321e802000-321ea02000 ---p 00002000 ca:01 450709                         /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
321ea02000-321ea03000 r--p 00002000 ca:01 450709                         /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
321ea03000-321ea04000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 450709                         /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
321ec00000-321ed8b000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450697                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
321ed8b000-321ef8a000 ---p 0018b000 ca:01 450697                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
321ef8a000-321ef8e000 r--p 0018a000 ca:01 450697                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
321ef8e000-321ef8f000 rw-p 0018e000 ca:01 450697                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
321ef8f000-321ef94000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
321f000000-321f017000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450771                         /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
321f017000-321f217000 ---p 00017000 ca:01 450771                         /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
321f217000-321f218000 r--p 00017000 ca:01 450771                         /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
321f218000-321f219000 rw-p 00018000 ca:01 450771                         /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
321f219000-321f21d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
321f800000-321f883000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450744                         /lib64/libm-2.12.so
321f883000-321fa82000 ---p 00083000 ca:01 450744                         /lib64/libm-2.12.so
321fa82000-321fa83000 r--p 00082000 ca:01 450744                         /lib64/libm-2.12.so
321fa83000-321fa84000 rw-p 00083000 ca:01 450744                         /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3220000000-322001d000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450775                         /lib64/libselinux.so.1
322001d000-322021c000 ---p 0001d000 ca:01 450775                         /lib64/libselinux.so.1
322021c000-322021d000 r--p 0001c000 ca:01 450775                         /lib64/libselinux.so.1
322021d000-322021e000 rw-p 0001d000 ca:01 450775                         /lib64/libselinux.so.1
322021e000-322021f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3220400000-322041d000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450780                         /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.7
322041d000-322061d000 ---p 0001d000 ca:01 450780                         /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.7
322061d000-3220621000 rw-p 0001d000 ca:01 450780                         /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.7
3220800000-3220802000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450782                         /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
3220802000-3220a01000 ---p 00002000 ca:01 450782                         /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
3220a01000-3220a02000 r--p 00001000 ca:01 450782                         /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
3220a02000-3220a03000 rw-p 00002000 ca:01 450782                         /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
3222000000-3222137000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 191042                         /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
3222137000-3222337000 ---p 00137000 ca:01 191042                         /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
3222337000-322233d000 rw-p 00137000 ca:01 191042                         /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
3223000000-3223002000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 191043                         /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
3223002000-3223202000 ---p 00002000 ca:01 191043                         /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
3223202000-3223203000 rw-p 00002000 ca:01 191043                         /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
3223800000-322381d000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 191231                         /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
322381d000-3223a1d000 ---p 0001d000 ca:01 191231                         /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
3223a1d000-3223a1e000 rw-p 0001d000 ca:01 191231                         /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
34df800000-34df817000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 409701                         /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6.3.0
34df817000-34dfa17000 ---p 00017000 ca:01 409701                         /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6.3.0
34dfa17000-34dfa18000 rw-p 00017000 ca:01 409701                         /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6.3.0
34dfa18000-34dfa1c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
372ec00000-372ec16000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450772                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
372ec16000-372ee15000 ---p 00016000 ca:01 450772                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
372ee15000-372ee16000 rw-p 00015000 ca:01 450772                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
39ef800000-39ef85f000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 415264                         /usr/lib64/libXt.so.6.0.0
39ef85f000-39efa5e000 ---p 0005f000 ca:01 415264                         /usr/lib64/libXt.so.6.0.0
39efa5e000-39efa64000 rw-p 0005e000 ca:01 415264                         /usr/lib64/libXt.so.6.0.0
39efa64000-39efa65000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
39efc00000-39efc04000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 455348                         /lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0Vim: Finished.
Vim: Double signal, exiting
*** glibc detected *** vim: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000002d138c0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x321ec76166]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x321ec79f9a]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x71)[0x321ec7a9a1]
vim[0x4c2540]
vim[0x4c3217]
vim[0x452cac]
vim[0x4711c2]
vim[0x45319c]
vim[0x453476]
vim[0x5984a5]
vim[0x4f6a23]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x321f00f710]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x321ec32925]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175)[0x321ec34105]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x321ec70837]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x321ec76166]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x321ec79f2f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x71)[0x321ec7a9a1]
vim[0x4c2540]
vim[0x4c3217]
vim[0x4471ba]
vim[0x4693eb]
vim[0x4676e3]
vim[0x45b190]
vim[0x457b1f]
vim[0x42e36a]
vim[0x43c54f]
vim[0x441c40]
vim[0x4405d3]
vim[0x440814]
vim[0x440a81]
vim[0x440e23]
vim[0x4416e4]
vim[0x441844]
vim[0x4422ee]
vim[0x44ada3]
vim[0x4693eb]
vim[0x4676e3]
vim[0x43b9d3]
vim[0x43c47c]
vim[0x441c40]
vim[0x4405d3]
vim[0x440814]
vim[0x440a81]
vim[0x440e23]
vim[0x4416e4]
vim[0x441844]
vim[0x441b59]
vim[0x4405d3]
vim[0x440814]
vim[0x440a81]
vim[0x440e23]
vim[0x4416e4]
vim[0x441844]
vim[0x4422ee]
vim[0x44ada3]
vim[0x4693eb]
vim[0x4676e3]
vim[0x43b9d3]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-007e3000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 188515                             /usr/bin/vim
009e2000-00a52000 rw-p 003e2000 ca:01 188515                             /usr/bin/vim
00a52000-00a79000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
028f9000-02d64000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
321e400000-321e420000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450684                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
321e61f000-321e620000 r--p 0001f000 ca:01 450684                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
321e620000-321e621000 rw-p 00020000 ca:01 450684                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
321e621000-321e622000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
321e800000-321e802000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450709                         /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
321e802000-321ea02000 ---p 00002000 ca:01 450709                         /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
321ea02000-321ea03000 r--p 00002000 ca:01 450709                         /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
321ea03000-321ea04000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 450709                         /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
321ec00000-321ed8b000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450697                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
321ed8b000-321ef8a000 ---p 0018b000 ca:01 450697                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
321ef8a000-321ef8e000 r--p 0018a000 ca:01 450697                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
321ef8e000-321ef8f000 rw-p 0018e000 ca:01 450697                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
321ef8f000-321ef94000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
321f000000-321f017000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450771                         /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
321f017000-321f217000 ---p 00017000 ca:01 450771                         /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
321f217000-321f218000 r--p 00017000 ca:01 450771                         /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
321f218000-321f219000 rw-p 00018000 ca:01 450771                         /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
321f219000-321f21d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
321f800000-321f883000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450744                         /lib64/libm-2.12.so
321f883000-321fa82000 ---p 00083000 ca:01 450744                         /lib64/libm-2.12.so
321fa82000-321fa83000 r--p 00082000 ca:01 450744                         /lib64/libm-2.12.so
321fa83000-321fa84000 rw-p 00083000 ca:01 450744                         /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3220000000-322001d000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450775                         /lib64/libselinux.so.1
322001d000-322021c000 ---p 0001d000 ca:01 450775                         /lib64/libselinux.so.1
322021c000-322021d000 r--p 0001c000 ca:01 450775                         /lib64/libselinux.so.1
322021d000-322021e000 rw-p 0001d000 ca:01 450775                         /lib64/libselinux.so.1
322021e000-322021f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3220400000-322041d000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450780                         /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.7
322041d000-322061d000 ---p 0001d000 ca:01 450780                         /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.7
322061d000-3220621000 rw-p 0001d000 ca:01 450780                         /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.7
3220800000-3220802000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450782                         /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
3220802000-3220a01000 ---p 00002000 ca:01 450782                         /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
3220a01000-3220a02000 r--p 00001000 ca:01 450782                         /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
3220a02000-3220a03000 rw-p 00002000 ca:01 450782                         /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
3222000000-3222137000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 191042                         /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
3222137000-3222337000 ---p 00137000 ca:01 191042                         /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
3222337000-322233d000 rw-p 00137000 ca:01 191042                         /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
3223000000-3223002000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 191043                         /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
3223002000-3223202000 ---p 00002000 ca:01 191043                         /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
3223202000-3223203000 rw-p 00002000 ca:01 191043                         /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
3223800000-322381d000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 191231                         /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
322381d000-3223a1d000 ---p 0001d000 ca:01 191231                         /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
3223a1d000-3223a1e000 rw-p 0001d000 ca:01 191231                         /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
34df800000-34df817000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 409701                         /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6.3.0
34df817000-34dfa17000 ---p 00017000 ca:01 409701                         /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6.3.0
34dfa17000-34dfa18000 rw-p 00017000 ca:01 409701                         /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6.3.0
34dfa18000-34dfa1c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
372ec00000-372ec16000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 450772                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
372ec16000-372ee15000 ---p 00016000 ca:01 450772                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
372ee15000-372ee16000 rw-p 00015000 ca:01 450772                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
39ef800000-39ef85f000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 415264                         /usr/lib64/libXt.so.6.0.0
39ef85f000-39efa5e000 ---p 0005f000 ca:01 415264                         /usr/lib64/libXt.so.6.0.0
39efa5e000-39efa64000 rw-p 0005e000 ca:01 415264                         /usr/lib64/libXt.so.6.0.0
39efa64000-39efa65000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
39efc00000-39efc04000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 455348                         /lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0
39efc04000-39efe03000 ---p 00004000 ca:01 455348                         /lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0
39efe03000-39efe04000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 455348                         /lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0
39f0000000-39f0007000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 415118                         /usr/lib64/libSM.so.6.0.1
39f0007000-39f0207000 ---p 00007000 ca:01 415118                         /usr/lib64/libSM.so.6.0.1
39f0207000-39f0208000 rw-p 00007000 ca:01 415118                         /usr/lib64/libSM.so.6.0.1
7f5f4cf9d000-7f5f4d1d1000 r-xp 00000000 ca:50 22418323                   /ebs/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.4m.so.1.0
7f5f4d1d1000-7f5f4d3d0000 ---p 00234000 ca:50 22418323                   /ebs/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.4m.so.1.0
7f5f4d3d0000-7f5f4d42d000 rw-p 00233000 ca:50 22418323                   /ebs/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.4m.so.1.0
7f5f4d42d000-7f5f4d448000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5f4d448000-7f5f4d44b000 r-xp 00000000 ca:50 23593585                   /ebs/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-34m.so
7f5f4d44b000-7f5f4d64a000 ---p 00003000 ca:50 23593585                   /ebs/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-34m.so
7f5f4d64a000-7f5f4d64d000 rw-p 00002000 ca:50 23593585                   /ebs/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-34m.so
7f5f4d64d000-7f5f4d7be000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5f4d7be000-7f5f4d7c5000 r--s 00000000 ca:01 197057                     /usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
7f5f4d7c5000-7f5f4d845000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5f4d845000-7f5f536d5000 r--p 00000000 ca:01 190504                     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f5f536d5000-7f5f536dd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5f536e1000-7f5f536e4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f5f536e5000-7f5f536e9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff206e5000-7fff20705000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff207f2000-7fff207f3000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: It looks like vim found the headers for a different version of python and has the symbols in the wrong places.

Comment: thank you. not totally sure what that means but just removed my entire .vim directory with plugins and no longer received the error. Something with the .vim plugin directory I was using with pathogen was causing an issue. not sure what though.

Comment: When you did `./configure`, vim tries to guess where python is located. It guessed wrong. You need to supply the `--with-python3-config-dir` when configuring vim. I believe vim won't load python if you don't have a plugin that requires python.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because vim didn't find the right version of python  You need to specify a python directory using `./configure --with-python3-config-dir [dir]`.

Comment: thank you but after seeing the below after running ./configure I was under the impression that it found the correct python and config dir also. (added to original answer)

Comment: Just added what my ./configure showed for the python it found.

Comment: @prometheus2305 The way I know about going about debugging this would be to use something like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to see where it went wrong.  But when its just vim that's extremely unnecessary.

With a little research I did find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059539/compiling-vim-with-python-support-on-ubuntu) which looks like it may solve your issue.

Comment: thank you. going to add my plugins again now that I'm not getting error. On a side note, doesn't feel like a great idea to keep original .vim plugin directory while re-installing vim.

Comment: So it definitely crashes whenever trying to create or open python files.
`Vim: Caught deadly signal ABRT
Vim: Finished.
Aborted (core dumped)` Really need to install vim with py3 support.